# S3 Authorization header in swift

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

I'm trying to send a multipart form request to S3 and according the [S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html) I can either add the signing information to the request in the authorization header or in the query string.  To me, the authorization header looks more straightforward.

`Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIDEXAMPLE/20150830/us-east 1/iam/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7`

In Swift, would this just be all one string like:

```
request.setValue("AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIDEXAMPLE/20150830/us-east 1/iam/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the `Authorization:` header nor the query string can be said to be particularly "more straightforward," since they are essentially constructed from the same information (other than the addition of `X-Amz-Expires`, and the necessary addition of the expiration logic to the signing code, as required in the query string)... but neither option is applicable here.

When using a form -- which is only done when doing an upload, so I assume that is what you are doing -- the signing information is provided as form parameters.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Comment: Thanks, I've been pretty lost in the documentation.  What is the difference between the sample at the top of the page and the one shown at the bottom of the page?  I noticed the top sample has an expiration while the bottom doesn't.

Comment: Query string (bottom) needs expiration incorporated into it, useful in case you want to expose the URL (to an authorized user) and want it to be valid for a specific period of time, with valid values ranging from 1 second to 7 days. Once set, expiration can't be tampered with, or the signature is invalidated. Authorization (top) is assumed to be a mechanism you'd use immediately after signing, so that method is valid for 15 minutes either side of the included timestamp.  Both mechanisms are computationally infeasible to reverse-engineer or tamper with.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  I thought in your answer, you said that authorization header and query string aren't applicable for an upload.  How come the link you provided shows the implementation of both styles for an upload?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment.  I thought you were asking about the link *you* posted, because in the link I posted, the two different sections are both used in a single request.  The form (bottom) *contains* the request you are sending, and the JSON policy document (top) *constrains* the request -- it specifies what is allowed (and required) in the form.  The expiration is an attribute of the policy, and as such it is part of the input to the signing algorithm.  The policy is signed, the form is not. The policy then becomes part of the form, as the `Policy` field encoded in Base-64.